# Access optional item label when defining label style with enumitem

Tags: enumitem, optional-arguments

I want to define a personalized `description` environment, which adds a boldface and brackets around the label name, so I'm using enumitem:

```
\newlist{named}{description}{1}
\setlist[named]{label=\textbf{(??)}}
```

What shall I put instead of ?? to access the optional argument passed to `\item` from the list?

To be as clear as possible, this is what I currently write:

```
\begin{description}
    \item[\textbf{(Hello)}] lorem ipsum...
\end{description}
```

and this is what I want to write (to accomplish the same result but to save some keystrokes):

```
\begin{named}
    \item[Hello] lorem ipsum...
\end{named}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You'll need a helper macro. The manual says that the commands in the `font` key can end with a macro taking one argument, which will be the item text.

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\newcommand\parens[1]{(#1)}
\setlist[description]{
  font=\bfseries\sffamily\parens,
}
\begin{document}

\begin{description}
\item[hello] 
\end{description}

\end{document}
```