# Custom environment with both numbering and named labels

Tags: lists, enumitem

I'd like to add arabic numbers to the custom environment described here:

[Access optional item label when defining label style with enumitem](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/444817/access-optional-item-label-when-defining-label-style-with-enumitem)

So to have this

```
\begin{enumerate}
    \item \emph{(Hello)} Lorem ipsum
    \item \emph{(World)} Dolor sit
\end{enumerate}
```

as the result of this:

```
\begin{named}
    \item[Hello] Lorem ipsum
    \item[World] Dolor sit
\end{named}
```

Varying on the solution of the linked question doesn't fully work because this

```
\newlist{named}{enumerate}{3}
\newcommand\parens[1]{(#1)}
\setlist[named]{
  label=\arabic*,
  font=\itshape\parens,
}
```

Doesn't show numbers and has a weird alignment (I'd like to have the same alignment as in the `description` environment).

Answer (score 1):

How about this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\newlist{named}{enumerate}{3}
\setlist[named]{
  label=\arabic*,
  labelsep=*,
}
\newcommand*\nameditem[1][]{%
  \item \hspace{-1em}\mbox{\itshape#1}%
}
\usepackage{microtype}
\frenchspacing

\begin{document}
\begin{named}
  \nameditem[Hello] Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer
    adipiscing elit. Etiam lobortis facilisis sem. Nullam nec mi
    et neque pharetra sollicitudin.
  \nameditem[World] Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer
    adipiscing elit. Etiam lobortis facilisis sem. Nullam nec mi
    et neque pharetra sollicitudin.
  \nameditem Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer
    adipiscing elit. Etiam lobortis facilisis sem. Nullam nec mi
    et neque pharetra sollicitudin.
\end{named}

\begin{description}
  \item[Hello] Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer
    adipiscing elit. Etiam lobortis facilisis sem. Nullam nec mi
    et neque pharetra sollicitudin.
  \item[World] Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer
    adipiscing elit. Etiam lobortis facilisis sem. Nullam nec mi
    et neque pharetra sollicitudin.
  \item Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer
    adipiscing elit. Etiam lobortis facilisis sem. Nullam nec mi
    et neque pharetra sollicitudin.
\end{description}
\end{document}
```

[image: lists]

I’m going to ignore the “ugly” space in the last item of the `description` list (it is supposed to have a `[description]` anyway).

Comment: Very clever! But it seems strange I can't achieve it with just plain $\item$. Just for curiosity, what is labelsep for?

Comment: @mattecapu The length `\labelsep` is not very intuitive: You can find a visual representation in Section 3.3 of the [`enumitem` manual](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/enumitem/enumitem.pdf). The key-value setup `labelsep=*` is described in the first paragraph of page 5.